# Problem logging in programatically to a website using WebBrowser Control

Tags: c#, javascript, webbrowser-control

I'm trying to login programatically to https://www.salesgenie.com/Account/LogOn using WebBrwoser control.

The problem is when I click on "Log On", the browser doesn't navigate to the next page in the LogonCompleted event.

```
HtmlElement userName = wBrowser.Document.GetElementById("username");
userName.SetAttribute("value", SomeUserName);

HtmlElement password = wBrowser.Document.GetElementById("password");
password.SetAttribute("value", SomePassword);

wBrowser.DocumentCompleted -= new WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventHandler(LogonPageLoaded);
wBrowser.DocumentCompleted += new WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventHandler(LogonCompleted);

HtmlElement logonForm = wBrowser.Document.GetElementById("logon-submit");
logonForm.InvokeMember("click");
```

I think this is because the element "logon-submit" calls a JavaScript function or so.

Please, any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out your 4th line, you're setting `userName` again when you should be setting `password`

**EDIT**

Besides the problem above I'm guessing that you're trying to invoke the click too soon. The button is created using JavaScript so you have to wait a bit before clicking it. Unfortunately there's no event that you can listen for to determine when the JavaScript is `done` although you could test various properties probably. The safest thing is to probably just wait a couple seconds after load before invoking `click`.

The code below works for me (although I don't have a valid username and password). I've got one button called `button1` and one webbrowser called `webBrowser1`. Once the page is visually loaded in the browser clicking the button on the form correctly invokes the `click` event in the browser.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            this.webBrowser1.Navigate("https://www.salesgenie.com/Account/LogOn");
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string SomeUserName = "Test";
            string SomePassword = "Test";

            HtmlElement userName = webBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("username");
            Console.WriteLine(userName.GetAttribute("value"));
            userName.SetAttribute("value", SomeUserName);
            userName.RemoveFocus();

            HtmlElement password = webBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("password");
            Console.WriteLine(userName.GetAttribute("value"));
            password.SetAttribute("value", SomePassword);

            HtmlElement logonForm = webBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("logon-submit");
            logonForm.InvokeMember("click");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Chris... but this wasn't the problem.

Comment: Actually, I don't click the "logon-submit" button until loads completely.

Comment: @Yas, ignoring the events for now, what happens in the browser itself? Do you see the spinning AJAX circle and then either an error message or something else?

Comment: My WebBrowser control is not visible in the form, but when I debug the code checking the DocumentText of the browser, I see the same login page.

Comment: @Yas, You're going to have to make the WebBrowser visible during the testing phase to see what's going on because the site you are targeting uses JavaScript heavily. When you click submit and AJAX call is made to validate so `DocumentText` would never change. You'll have to look at the actual DOM or monitor JavaScript events in some way. Or, unless you have a need for it, drop the `WebBrowser` control completely and just screen scrape using `System.Net.WebClient` or `HttpWebRequest`.

Comment: I think I'll choose to scrape using HttpWebRequest. But can I login and navigate to the desired page using HttpWebRequest?

Comment: If you use HttpWebRequest you'll be creating and parsing raw HTTP requests and responses which is what the WebBrowser control does for you. It will not parse HTML or run any JavaScripts or anything like that. But as long as you know the names of the fields that you need to POST and where to send it its a lot easier (at least for me). Use a program like Fiddler to inspect raw headers from your browser.

Comment: Thanks Chris.. I tried Watin, seems to be the best for my case.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try using logonForm.click(); ?   Without invoking any member ?